# No se puede resolver el símbolo @Transactional

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Estoy trabajando con la última versión de java y Maven para crear un api pero al crear mi DAOImp me sale error al tratar de usar la anotación @Transactional me pide que agregue la dependencia que se necesita, pero no me agrega la dependencia y si agrego el import me sale el mismo error "Cannot resolve symbol 'tansaction'", necesito su ayuda por favor.

anexo el codigo de la clase imp e imagen.

```
package com.cursojava2.curso2.dao;

import com.cursojava2.curso2.models.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImp implements UserDAO{
    @Override
    public List<User> getUsuario() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo dentro de mi POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cursojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>curso</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Qué dependencias tienes en el POM?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-tomcat, spring-boot-starter-test, spring-test, spring-context y estaba intentando agregar la de spring-tx pero no me deja porque no la encuentra en el repositorio y estoy usando IntelliJ Idea

Comment: agrega tu pom a la pregunta para darnos una idea de tus dependencias

Comment: he agregado mi pom y gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que necesitas añadir las dependencias de JPA:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya se arregló el error

Comment: Pregunta podras explicar como lo solucionaste ? sigo sin saber como solucionarlo .